# How to replace more strings in a variable?

Tags: javascript

In Php it's easy:

```
str_replace (array(...), array(...), $subject)
```

But how to do it in javascript?

Comment: Loop on one of your arrays, and use [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) sequentially.

Comment: This may help you out: http://www.roseindia.net/java/javascript-array/replace-element.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
​var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
var b = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"];
var stringa = "one to two to three";
```

And then:​​​​

```
for (i in a) {
    if (i < b.length) {         
       stringa = stringa.replace(a[i], b[i]);
    }    
}
console.log(stringa);
```

​

Answer (score 3):

If you want a complete analogue, there's an implementation: http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace:527

Answer (score 3):

Just call `.replace()` again:

```
 var someVar = 'Hello I am a string';
 var modified = someVar.replace('Hello', 'Goodbye').replace('am', 'was');
 console.log(modified); // Goodbye I was a string
```

Remember that the `String.replace()` javascript method is actually like a combination of PHP's `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` - the first argument can be a regex as well as a string. So you can also do:

```
 var someVar = 'Hello I am a string';
 var modified = someVar.replace(/(hello|string)/ig, 'Goat!').replace('am', 'was');
 console.log(modified); // Goat! I was a Goat!
```

Answer (score 2):

[phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org/) has converted PHP functions to JS equivalents (including str_replace).